# How to edit R plots generated by other function that uses plot to create it?

Tags: r, function, plot, edit

I'm using the `EFACompData` from the package `RGenData`, which can create a plot. However, I want to remove the frame from that plot. How can I do it? The function `EFACompData` does not have an option to do it.

```
x <- matrix(nrow = 200, ncol = 9)
for (i in 1:3) {
  shared <- rchisq(200, 1)
  for (j in 1:3) {
    x[, (i - 1) * 3 + j] <- shared + rchisq(200, 1)
  }
}

EFACompData(x, f.max = 5,graph = T)
```

Comment: Looks like this uses `base` plots, which (unlike `ggplot`s) can't be edited. Your only option is to edit the function `EFACompData`.

Comment: Yap, I did. But I would like to know if it is possible to change without going to the function itself. Thank you.

Comment: Nope. As I said above, your only option is to edit the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `EFACompData` uses base graphics, you could try modifying graphical parameters via suitable `par` settings *prior* to calling the plot function. For example,

```
par(bty = "n")
EFACompData(x, f.max = 5, graph = TRUE)
```

will suppress the box surrounding the plot region. Of course, this only works if the plot function doesn't modify the parameter itself. For `EFACompData` it works. See `help("par")` for further graphical parameters.

Note that subsequent "editing" of base graphics is limited to *adding* things to the current plot via low-level plotting commands such as `points`, `lines`, `text`, `title`, or `legend`.